# For which $g,p$ does $\Sigma_{g,p}$ cover $\Sigma_{3,2}$? 

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am preparing for my qualifying exams. There is an algebraic topology problem I don't know how to do it. Thanks a lot for your help.

> Let $\Sigma_{g,p}$ denote the surface of genus $g$ with $p$ punctures.
>   For what $g,p$ does $\Sigma_{g,p}$ cover $\Sigma_{3,2}$?

I know how to do this problem without punctures. Have no idea how to deal with the punctures.

Comment: I once tried a problem like this using polar coordinates. The instructor said my argument was full of holes...

Comment: Were you able to find a reference for these kinds of problems? I am also studying for qual exams and I'm not sure how to solve this, and I've seen these types of questions on several of the previous exams.